# Can old unanswered questions appear on the homepage again?

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to reopen the question which was really unanswered, because user read latest questions mostly?

Not to offence Sir :)

"Sometimes you ask a question, and specifically in that day, if it was noticed by someone else and they know the answer, we have chance to get correct answers." - Excellent

"But sometimes you do not know the answer, as a result it keeps going to the underground or stay without answer, for years, month, days." - Its ok, i am good but can we not help on those questions too? Like a reminder tab or random unanswered tab (jack pot)

Is it possible to click that question after 1 week if not answered to rollback on top of readers, or such as another new tab which says "I was Old, questions", kind of follow up or reminder to solve many questions which is living as junk but may have hope to get answers just because readers do not read anymore the old records?

Note: When you search google it shows 1 millions of records, but mostly you, me we check the first 100 page maximium, the last records are old

Answer (score 3):

This already happens to some extent. There is a Community "user" on the site which performs a number of automated functions for Ask Ubuntu - one of them is to push old, unanswered questions with low views back on to the front page. This gives them a second, third, and even fourth "chance" at getting answered.

However, there are other ways to get your question back into the frontpage stream. Constantly editing your question to add additional details and narrate things you've tried (if you're trying to troubleshoot) will put your question on the frontpage after each edit. So as long as you keep contributing to your questions body content and improving it's quality, it'll keep showing up on the frontpage.

Lastly questions that leave the frontpage aren't close or gone forever. Unanswered questions show up in the [Unanswered Queue](https://askubuntu.com/unanswered) which users frequently check in order to ensure that everyone gets there question answered! The Unanswered page allows you to sort by date question was asked, the question's score, by tags you're interested in, or just show questions with 0 answers.